# Dynamic SQL stored procedure not populating temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am using a stored procedure with one parameter (`@tablename`) to generate a table of attributes about the table named via the parameter.

I call the stored procedure as follows

```
EXEC sp_Schema_Presentation @tablename = 'UserID'
```

And run the stored procedure (at the bottom of this post).

- I have created a `@DynamicSQL` string in order to use my `@tablename` parameter. However, the `SELECT` statement, in which it's used, also creates the `#TEMP` table.
- The rest of the query uses this `#TEMP` table so I `DECLARE` its structure at the top.
- However, when I run the stored procedure, the `#TEMP` table is empty

If I hard code the `@tablename`, the query will work. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
    SampleKey nvarchar(MAX), 
    SampleData nvarchar(MAX)
)

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT B.*
INTO dbo.#TEMP
FROM (
     SELECT * FROM ' + @Tablename + N' ORDER BY 1 DESC
     OFFSET 1 ROWS
     FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
    ) A

    CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT [Key] AS SampleKey
                  ,Value AS SampleData
                  FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* FOR JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) )

               ) B'
```

Full stored procedure in SQL Server 2016:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Schema_Presentation]
    @TableName nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
    (
         SampleKey nvarchar(MAX), 
         SampleData nvarchar(MAX)
    )

    DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT B.*
                         INTO dbo.#TEMP
                         FROM (
                              SELECT * FROM ' + @Tablename + N' ORDER BY 1 DESC
                              OFFSET 1 ROWS
                              FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
                              ) A
                         CROSS APPLY (
                                      SELECT [Key] AS SampleKey
                                      ,Value AS SampleData
                                      FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* FOR JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) )

                                      ) B'

       DECLARE @Columns as NVARCHAR(MAX)
       SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
         FROM
            (
              SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM PRESENTATION_PP.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N''' + @TableName + '''
          ) AS B

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL

        SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME,
                     CASE WHEN a.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%[_]_key' THEN a.COLUMN_NAME
                           ELSE REPLACE(a.COLUMN_NAME,'_',' ') END AS DISPLAY_NAME,
                           a.DATA_TYPE, COALESCE(a.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,  a.NUMERIC_PRECISION) AS SIZE,
                     CASE WHEN NUMERIC_SCALE IS NULL THEN 0
                           ELSE NUMERIC_SCALE END AS SCALE,
                           a.IS_NULLABLE AS NULLABLE,
                     CASE WHEN i.is_primary_key IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES'
                           ELSE 'NO' END AS PK,
                     #TEMP.SampleData
       FROM PRESENTATION_PP.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
                     LEFT JOIN
                           sys.columns c ON a.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
                     LEFT JOIN
                           sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
                     LEFT JOIN
                           sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                     LEFT JOIN
                           #TEMP ON a.COLUMN_NAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI = #TEMP.SampleKey COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
       WHERE TABLE_NAME =  @TableName AND c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
        SELECT * FROM #TEMP
       DROP TABLE #TEMP

END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Another side note: It is also good practice to use `QUOTENAME()` when inserting names into dynamic SQL. This allows for names containing spaces, special characters, or reserved words. It also prevents SQL injection from someone adding a carefully crafted table name.  (Nice tool by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `#Temp` table first, and then `INSERT INTO` not `Select ... Into #Temp`

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (SampleKey nvarchar(MAX), SampleData nvarchar(MAX))

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DynamicSQL = N'
Insert Into #Temp
SELECT B.*
FROM (
     SELECT * FROM ' + @Tablename + N' ORDER BY 1 DESC
     OFFSET 1 ROWS
     FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
    ) A
    CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT [Key] AS SampleKey
                  ,Value AS SampleData
                  FROM OpenJson( (SELECT A.* FOR JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) )
               ) B
'

Exec(@DynamicSQL)


Select * from #Temp
```